# Should events delegation be implemented on bubbling or capturing phase

Tags: javascript

[This article](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) states that:

> The key to event delegation is to use the bubbling aspect of events to
> handle them at the highest level (usually document).

I always thought that it's better to implement event delegation on the capturing phase. In this way it's event possible to stopPropagation() at all to children and probably save some operations. Am I wrong?